# Change Behavior of <C-b> to Move Cursor at the Top of the Page in VIM

Tags: vim, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts, neovim

I just started using `<C-b>` and `<C-u>` in vim. I am aware that `<C-b>` moves the page up and that `<C-u>` moves the page up by half. However, I noticed that `<C-b>` keeps the cursor at the bottom of the page whereas `<C-u>` keeps the cursor at the top of the page.

I was wondering if there is a good reason for this and if it would be worth changing. For example, change the behavior of `<C-b>` to move the cursor at the top of the page so that both `<C-b>` and `<C-u>` have the same behavior and make it easier for me to expect where the cursor will be. I think this might make it easier for me as I won't have to remember where the cursor will go all the time based on which combination I used.

If it is worth changing, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: I'm noticing that `<C-u>` "moves the cursor at the top of the page" only "on the first page" i.e. when it can't scroll-up anymore, otherwise it keeps the cursors at the same position more or less (at least on vanilla vim)

Comment: I guess I might have not explained it very well. If your cursor is at the bottom of the page <C-u> scrolls up half the page, but once the cursor reaches the top of the page and you keep scrolling up using <C-u> it keeps the cursor at the top of the page. On the other hand <C-b> keeps the cursor at the bottom of the page. I'll make sure to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remap  to move cursor where you want:

```
map <C-U> <C-U>L
```

`L` move cursor to the bottom of screen (to remember - Low). See `:h L`. There also `H` (to remember - High) for the top of screen and `M` motions the middle.

Comment: That works, thanks! Would you think this is worth doing though?

Comment: Hard to say, because I do not use <C-U> and use <C-B> rarely. It depend on your use case, just try it for few hours and you will see =)